# Rstudio Preview (Version 0.99.1282) can't publish in Rpubs

Tags: markdown, rstudio, knitr

I just updated to the newest version of Rstudio Preview (Version 0.99.1282)  and built ioslides. However, when I tried to publish them in RPubs through the "Publish" bottom, it automatically went to the window asking for a "RStudio Connect Account." (As a Windows user, it seems not an available option for me.) There is no option to connect to my RPubs as before. How can I submit my slides onto the RPubs.com ?

Comment: Where are you clicking the Publish button -- in the editor? the viewer window for the presentation? file menu?

Comment: I tried the publish button at the top right corner of both the editor and the viewer window. Both showed the same options "Publish Document..." and "Manage accounts..." By selecting the former, it goes to the process requiring for a RStudio Connect Account. @Jonathan